# drawable issue in Imageview

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview

I got the error

> , , AidlTokenType.import or AidlTokenType.package expected, got '@'

Piece of codes-

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
                    android:layout_width="164dp"
                    android:layout_height="51dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/value_2"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/value_2"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/value_2"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

I'm getting error on the last line i.e. `android:src="@drawable/logo"`

Comment: This is highly unlikely to be caused by imageview

Comment: refere this article https://medium.com/@garrylaly/android-studio-1-4-error-aidltokentype-import-or-aidltokentype-package-expected-got-9ea2ddd85ec7